PromQL query for specific duration
Stuck on a simple task.
The request should only be processed if the request condition is true for more than 10 minutes.
Let's say
cpuLoad{instance="1.1.1.1"}>80
It should be output only if this condition is true for more than 10 minutes
I was here https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#time, but nothing helped me)
Query for grafana in prometheus datasource

What are you trying to do with this: alert or visualization? If latter, how you intend this to be visualized: like item only present once 10m threshold met, or as graph?

I just needed an alert

You can use avg_over_time() as cpuLoad should be instant value.
Query for CpuLoad for instance="1.1.1.1" should be greater than 80 for more than 10 minutes is
avg_over_time(cpuLoad{instance="1.1.1.1"}[10m]) > 80

I don’t know how I didn’t choose this function, because I tried it, but I didn’t like something, but it will work, thank you)

I think I’ve found a solution for myself, maybe not a pretty one, but a working one
(cpuLoad{instance="1.1.1.1"}>80+cpuLoad{instance="1.1.1.1"}offset 10m >80 )>160
For some reason my logic didn't work:
(metric-metric offset 10m) >0

mitric-mitric works :) -  ((metric>80)-(metric offset 10m >80)) >0
